# Android Studio Locale.SWEDISH not found

Tags: android

I try to make multilingual app for Android, but there's no Finnish or Swedish language in Locales.

What's wrong?

I also tried to use
`Locale.forLanguageTag("se")`
But it didn't work on my Samsung Galaxy SII.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSUVo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not wrong, it simply does not exist.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: Oh. Is there any way to make Swedish app?

Comment: Sure, create different "strings.xml" files, one for each language you need to support. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Android Studio helps you. When you create a new resource you can assign  it to a particular configuration (language, screen size, resolution, etc). Final devices will take the right resource automatically ;)

Comment: For Finnish create the directory "values-fi", for Swedish "values-sv". Or better let Android Studio to create them for you

Comment: Yes, I already got that right, but I also want to change language from the application.

Comment: You should be able to do that. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android

Create a new Locale by passing "fi" or "sv" and using it as the answer says (it is not important to have the constant Locale.SOMETHING)